# Detect when backup of database is done

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-backups

I'm doing backup of database through code:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
       var query = String.Format("BACKUP DATABASE [{0}] TO DISK='{1}'", databaseName, fileName);

       using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
       {
           connection.Open();
           command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
}
```

The return value od `ExecuteNonQuery()` is useless because I get as result -1.
Is there any other way do detect when the backup is done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38060528/2946329

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266833/should-i-use-executenonquery-for-this-db-backup-command

Comment: you can always watch the file and check if the last modified was updated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a SQL script that I can use to determine the progress of a SQL Server backup or restore process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152447/is-there-a-sql-script-that-i-can-use-to-determine-the-progress-of-a-sql-server-b)

Answer (score 1):

You can either check if the file is in the destination or you can wrap your code in try catch and set a flag `success = false` when there is an exception.